# Stats/Probability - Poisson Distribution - How do I calculate the probability between two points in R?

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

I need to find `P(400<=X<=500)` in one year using R

**Given:**

*Poisson Distribution*

Lambda = E(X) = 1.3 crimes per day = *474.5 per year*

The only methods I can find online are to manually input numbers 400-500 using dpois, I really have no idea how to use R very well so if someone could help me that would be much appreciated.

[relevant question outlined in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxoH2.png)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: I agree this is off-topic and lacks the recommended context. But now that has been explained, and it is easier to answer than to explain why not to answer. // In R, `dpois` and `ppois` are Poisson PDF and CDF, respectively, so code: `sum(dpois(400:500, 474.5))` returns
$0.8828723$ and so does code `diff(ppois(c(399,500), 474.5))`.

Comment: @JitendraSingh Thanks for your reply. I did look around quickly before I made the post for some sort of introduction on how to post to get an idea of how to use the forum, but I couldn't find one. Appreciate the heads up.

Comment: @BruceET Thanks for your answer, much appreciated. I sometimes find it easier to work backwards from an answer when I am stumped, as this helps me hone in and understand the right concepts. This will help me get my head around using R to solve distribution probabilities so thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following three events:

1. $A: X \lt 400$
2. $B: X \leq 500$
3. $C: 400 \leq X \leq 500$

Note that $A$ and $C$ are mutually exclusive, and that $A \cup C = B$. So if you can find the probability of $A$ and $C$, you should be able to find the probability of $B$.

To find those probabilities in R, notice that when you look up distributions in the help file that there's usually one function starting with `d` that gives the density function, and another starting with `p` that gives the *cumulative* density, which may be more useful here.

Comment: Not really an answer (which may be inappropriate here), better as a comment. In any case, perhaps better to say $P(400\le X \le 500) = P(X\le 500) - P(X\le 399).$ There is almost no probability below 399.